# Why does app keep stopping?

Tags: java, android

I cannot figure out why my app keeps stopping. I have a gridlayout with four buttons arranged in a two by two square, each button having a number. Everytime a button is pressed, a new problem is generated and displayed in a textview, and new numbers are assigned to the 4 buttons. Below is the method I'm using to assign the new numbers:

```
public void assignAnswers(int rightAnswer) {
    int chooseButton = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
    int answerPossibility = 0;
    Button answerChoice = (Button) answersGridLayout.findViewWithTag("" + chooseButton);
    answerChoice.setText("" + rightAnswer);
    ArrayList<Integer> answersAdded = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if(i != chooseButton) {
            Button newAnswerChoice = (Button) answersGridLayout.findViewWithTag("" + i);
            boolean repeat = false;
            do {
                switch (operation) {
                    case "+":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(41);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(41) - 20;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(401);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(61);
                        break;
                }

                for(int j = 0; j < answersAdded.size(); j++) {
                    if(answerPossibility == answersAdded.get(j) || answerPossibility == rightAnswer) repeat = true;
                }
            } while(repeat);
            answersAdded.add(answerPossibility);
            newAnswerChoice.setText("" + answerPossibility);
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I run my app, it works for a variable number of times then stops and the buttons do not respond to being pressed anymore. Additionally, no errors are shown in the Android monitor. I know the problem has to be in the above method since when I comment this method out, the rest of the app works perfectly and never stops. Also, `rightAnswer` is correctly calculated and returned from another method. `operation` as well (it's a class variable).

Thanks for the help. I'm very new to this stuff and can use all your input.

Edit: Here's what I think is the stacktrace:

```
08-04 12:55:07.391 1685-1694/com.android.systemui I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

[ 08-04 12:55:07.404  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1296

[ 08-04 12:55:07.404  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1307 uid=1041 gid=1005 tid=1307


[ 08-04 12:55:07.413  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1307

[ 08-04 12:55:07.413  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1308 uid=1047 gid=1005 tid=1308


[ 08-04 12:55:07.418  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1308

[ 08-04 12:55:07.419  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1310 uid=1019 gid=1019 tid=1310


[ 08-04 12:55:07.422  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1310

[ 08-04 12:55:07.422  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1313 uid=1046 gid=1006 tid=1313


[ 08-04 12:55:07.427  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1313

[ 08-04 12:55:07.427  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1314 uid=1013 gid=1031 tid=1314


[ 08-04 12:55:07.433  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1314

[ 08-04 12:55:07.433  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1315 uid=1040 gid=1026 tid=1315


[ 08-04 12:55:07.437  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1315

[ 08-04 12:55:07.438  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1316 uid=1013 gid=1005 tid=1316


[ 08-04 12:55:07.444  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1316

[ 08-04 12:55:07.444  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1684 uid=1023 gid=1023 tid=1684


[ 08-04 12:55:07.448  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1684

[ 08-04 12:55:07.448  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1760 uid=1023 gid=1023 tid=1760


[ 08-04 12:55:07.452  1245: 1245 W/]
debuggerd: resuming target 1760

08-04 12:55:08.032 1590-1606/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.saint.speedmathtrainer (com.saint.speedmathtrainer/.MainActivity)
                                                               PID: 23729
                                                               Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 5789.0ms.)
                                                               Load: 0.36 / 0.17 / 0.22
                                                               CPU usage from 43635ms to 0ms ago (2017-08-04 12:54:23.642 to 2017-08-04 12:55:07.277):
                                                                 3.1% 1296/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 3.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                 1.8% 1590/system_server: 0.1% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 5954 minor
                                                                 1.5% 1300/adbd: 0% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 20294 minor
                                                                 0.3% 2327/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 2109 minor
                                                                 0.3% 1307/audioserver: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 21 minor
                                                                 0.2% 1685/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 219 minor
                                                                 0.1% 1785/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 173 minor
                                                                 0.1% 2083/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 434 minor
                                                                 0% 2006/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 57 minor
                                                                 0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 11/migration/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 1233/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 1244/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
                                                                 0% 1294/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 1295/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 1318/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 1677/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 2220/kworker/1:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 0% 4672/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                +0% 23729/com.saint.speedmathtrainer: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               23% TOTAL: 18% user + 5% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.3% softirq
                                                               CPU usage from 234ms to 746ms later (2017-08-04 12:55:07.510 to 2017-08-04 12:55:08.022):
                                                                 100% 23729/com.saint.speedmathtrainer: 100% user + 0% kernel
                                                                   102% 23729/peedmathtrainer: 102% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 1.7% 1307/audioserver: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
                                                                 1.9% 1590/system_server: 0% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                   1.9% 1598/FinalizerDaemon: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
                                                                   1.9% 1606/ActivityManager: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
                                                               52% TOTAL: 50% user + 1.9% kernel
08-04 12:55:08.065 1296-2027/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
08-04 12:55:08.066 1590-29331/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-04 12:55:08.066 1590-29331/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-04 12:55:08.066 1590-29331/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-04 12:55:08.066 1590-29331/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-04 12:55:08.076 1296-2027/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
08-04 12:55:08.089 1296-2027/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
08-04 12:55:08.271 1307-1335/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xab6030c0) throttle end: throttle time(1)
08-04 12:55:08.286 1590-29331/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x89de4100 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x882af950
08-04 12:55:08.477 1590-1613/system_process W/AppOps: Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
08-04 12:55:13.139 2030-24271/com.google.android.gms W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
08-04 13:01:00.964 2006-2006/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #0 of 5: 15616 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.964 2006-2006/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #1 of 5: 15640 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.964 2006-2006/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #2 of 5: 15640 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.964 2006-2006/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #3 of 5: 15636 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.964 2006-2006/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #4 of 5: 14632 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.965 2998-3010/com.google.android.gms.unstable D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #0 of 5: 16836 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.965 2998-3010/com.google.android.gms.unstable D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #1 of 5: 16856 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.965 2998-3010/com.google.android.gms.unstable D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #2 of 5: 16856 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.965 2998-3010/com.google.android.gms.unstable D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #3 of 5: 16856 bytes
08-04 13:01:00.965 2998-3010/com.google.android.gms.unstable D/StrictMode: Wrote violation #4 of 5: 15848 bytes
08-04 13:01:01.005 1314-3263/? D/WVCdm: Instantiating CDM.
08-04 13:01:01.006 1314-1333/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::OpenSession
08-04 13:01:01.006 1314-1333/? I/WVCdm: Level3 Library 4464 Sep 10 2016 21:49:53
08-04 13:01:01.007 1314-1333/? W/WVCdm: Could not load liboemcrypto.so. Falling back to L3.  dlopen failed: library "liboemcrypto.so" not found
08-04 13:01:01.013 1314-1333/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::QueryKeyControlInfo
08-04 13:01:01.013 1314-3236/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::GenerateKeyRequest
08-04 13:01:01.013 1314-3236/? D/WVCdm: PrepareKeyRequest: nonce=2676645328
08-04 13:01:01.099 1314-1314/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::CloseSession
08-04 13:01:01.103 2006-2666/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/art: Long monitor contention with owner netscheduler-queue-handler (3046) at void rou.a(rpn, int)(:com.google.android.gms:344) waiters=0 in boolean rou.c() for 172ms
08-04 13:01:01.171 2006-29599/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
08-04 13:01:01.174 2006-29599/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
08-04 13:01:01.698 2998-2998/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/Binder:2998_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:18): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=3072 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
08-04 13:01:01.804 2006-3111/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: null
08-04 13:01:01.870 2006-3111/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: null
08-04 13:01:01.941 2006-3111/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
                                                                          java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
                                                                              at evk.a(:com.google.android.gms:274)
                                                                              at evk.a(:com.google.android.gms:4238)
                                                                              at evj.a(:com.google.android.gms:45)
                                                                              at evd.a(:com.google.android.gms:50)
                                                                              at evc.a(:com.google.android.gms:104)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms:4049)
                                                                              at ecm.call(:com.google.android.gms:2041)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                              at llt.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                              at lqc.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-04 13:10:10.118 1590-1654/system_process D/WifiNative-HAL: Failing getSupportedFeatureset because HAL isn't started
08-04 13:10:10.119 1590-1609/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
08-04 13:10:10.119 1590-1609/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-04 13:10:10.122 1590-1609/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
08-04 13:10:10.123 1590-1609/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
08-04 13:10:10.123 1590-1609/system_process E/KernelWakelockReader: neither /proc/wakelocks nor /d/wakeup_sources exists
08-04 13:10:10.123 1590-1609/system_process W/BatteryStatsImpl: Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
08-04 13:10:10.123 1590-1609/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
08-04 13:10:15.195 2030-5935/com.google.android.gms W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
08-04 13:11:00.046 1590-1606/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 2ms
08-04 13:11:11.773 2030-6863/com.google.android.gms I/EventLogChimeraService: Aggregate from 1501868471670 (log), 1501868471670 (data)
08-04 13:11:16.914 2030-6865/com.google.android.gms W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Update:**
I've fixed my problem. After looking through the error logs above, I noticed this line:

```
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 5789.0ms.)
```

From this, I concluded (rightly or not, I'm not sure) that I had included too many loops in my method for it to work quickly enough and keep up with my clicks (the buttons are meant to be pressed in relatively rapid succession). Since this method worked as is without the `for` loop within my `if` statement, I removed this and put it in a separate method, as shown below:

```
public boolean checkRepeat(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList, int answerP, int answerC) {
    boolean repeatCheck = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
        if(answerP == arrayList.get(j) || answerP == answerC) repeatCheck = true;
    }
    return repeatCheck;
}

public void assignAnswers(int rightAnswer) {
    int chooseButton = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
    int answerPossibility = 0;
    Button answerChoice = (Button) answersGridLayout.findViewWithTag("" + chooseButton);
    answerChoice.setText("" + rightAnswer);
    ArrayList<Integer> answersAdded = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if(i != chooseButton) {
            Button newAnswerChoice = (Button) answersGridLayout.findViewWithTag("" + i);
            boolean repeat = false;
            do {
                switch (operation) {
                    case "+":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(41);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(41) - 20;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(401);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        answerPossibility = rand.nextInt(61);
                        break;
                }
                repeat = checkRepeat(answersAdded, answerPossibility, rightAnswer);
            } while(repeat);
            answersAdded.add(answerPossibility);
            newAnswerChoice.setText("" + answerPossibility);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm assuming calling a bunch of methods in another method is faster than simply combining all the code from each method into a single method. Could anyone confirm/qualify this and perhaps explain why this is so? Thanks again.

Comment: "Additionally, no errors are shown in the Android monitor" -- then what do you mean by "my app keeps stopping"? If your app is crashing, there will be a stack trace in LogCat.

Comment: check logcat for the stacktrace to where it all goes wrong and add that to your question

Comment: So, I've added what you've asked (i think). Hopefully this will help.